# How to turn off Envelope and Body in SOAP request

Tags: c++, soap, web, service, clickatell

This is critical to my current project. I have written a client in C++ using Windows web services. This client talks to the Clickatell SMS SOAP web service. I have tested the request using the SOAPUI tool and get correct response. I also receive the SMS message. Now, when I do this programmatically it fails because the WsCall() [in the code generated from WSDL via wsutil.exe) inserts  even though the SOAP request I have already includes Envelope and Body. I cannot take out my Envelope since I have namespace specified in it like this:
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:tns=\"soap.clickatell.com\">
I know that the additional Envelope and Body are inserted since I see it in the Fiddler tool.
Any help I can get is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the older type rpc/encoded soap api.

Have you tried using the document/literal service?
(http://api.clickatell.com/soap/document_literal/webservice.php?wsdl)